# How to change status of Uber request from processing to request

Tags: android, curl, uber-api

I am building an android app that uses the Uber API ride request endpoint. Using Sandbox I am having trouble changing the ride request status properly. I have tried updating it with the curl command Uber has in their docs and it is showing error that endpoint not supported.

These are curl command-

curl -X PUT 'https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/requests/{REQUEST_ID}' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ' \
  -d '{"status":"accepted"}'

and This is my code to change status,

public JSONObject getStatus
(String address, String requestId, String product_id, float start_latitude, float start_longitude, float end_latitude, float end_longitude, String token)
 {
        try 
           {

```
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpput = new HttpPut(address);

        **params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", "accepted"));**
        httpput.setHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+token);
        httpput.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        httpput.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpput);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "in getstatus");
        }
        is.close();

        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSONStr", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jObj;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide an example request/response? The following will work:

  curl -X PUT 'https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/requests/{REQUEST_ID}'
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>'
  -d '{"status":"accepted"}'

Comment: I am not getting where to append status

Comment: Change the json post data { "status": "accepted" } to another status like `arriving` or `in_progress` in the json example above ^.